# Index setting path in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos DB, I have an index setting that looks like this:

```json
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/PartitionKey/*"
        }
    ]
```

What would be the difference if I changed the `Path` to only this: "/PartitionKey"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means indexing won't be enabled on the nested nodes in the document. The path to anything under **/PartitionKey/**. The character * should be used if you are planing to query on sub properties of the property for this path.

from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy),

> the /* wildcard can be used to match any elements below the node

If you don't have nested nodes then this should be good enough. Also you need to use the `?` character at the end of the index path is required to serve queries that query on this property.

```
/PartitionKey/?
```